# How do you convert SpatialPoints object to PPP object?

Tags: polygon, point, density, spatstat

I have a shapefile layer of polygons (houses in a city) that I want to run a kernel density on using the density() function in spatstat in R. To get my polygons as points I turned them into SpatialPoints using:
`houses_points <- SpatialPoints(houses)`

Now I have my houses polygons as points, but I now need to convert these SpatialPoints to a PPP object, so I can plug them into the density() function. How can I do this?

I have tried using:
`houses_points <- as(houses, "ppp")`

and get the following error message:

`Error in as(houses, "ppp") : no method or default for coercing “SpatialPolygonsDataFrame” to “ppp”`

Comment: Should it not be "houses_points <- as(houses_points, "ppp")" as you are still pointing to houses in your ppp convertion.

Comment: Could be nice if you actually did a minimal coding example and provided context in form of purpose for transforming to PPP-object.